# Error: read ECONNRESET and Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, scraping

Boa noite galera.
Estou fazendo raspagens (web scraping) de um site, estou utilizando as cheerio e axios do NodeJS.
Quando executo a aplicação ele funciona perfeitamente me trazendo as informações que solicitei, porém ele me da esse erro as vezes, e nunca termina de pegar todas informações, sempre parando no caminho...

Desde já agradeço pela atenção!